# Diferença entre promise.then( sucess, error ) e promise.then() .catch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Olá,

Gostaria de esclarecer a diferença e quando usar cada dos modelos de tratamento das promessas:

```
obj.promessa( parametro ).then( function ( resposta ) {
    console.log("Resposta: " + resposta);
}, function ( erro ) {
    console.log("Erro: " + erro);
});
```

e

```
obj.promessa( parametro ).then( function ( resposta ) {
    console.log("Resposta: " + resposta);
}).catch( function ( erro ) {
    console.log("Erro: " + erro);
});
```

Considerando que o método obj.promessa fosse algo do tipo:

```
promessa: function( parametro ) {
   var deferred = q.defer();
   if ( fun_assincrona(parametro) ) {
      return deffered.resolve("sucesso");
   } else {
      return deferred.reject("error");
   }
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Abraços!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em termos gerais eu diria assim:

- usa `.catch()` 1 vez por encadeamento de promises, para apanhar erros imprevistos
- usa localmente a função de erro para corrigir erros e permitir ao encadeamento continuar

Vou dar dois exemplos, um que sofre um erro, mas que é corrigido, outro que sofre um erro, sem o corrigir:

#### Corrigindo erros localmente com função erro.

```js
function resolve(contador) {
    contador++
    console.log('Iteração', contador);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => res(contador), 200);
    });
}

function falha(contador) {
    contador++;
    console.log('Eu vou falhar na iteração', contador);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => rej(contador), 200);
    });
}
resolve(0)
    .then(resolve)
    .then(falha) // <-----------------
    .then(function() {
        // esta função é do success e não vai ser chamada
    }, function(nr) {
        console.log('Houve um erro, mas eu vou dar sinal para continuar...');
        return resolve(nr)
    })
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

#### Deixando erros para o `.catch()`

```js
function resolve(contador) {
  contador++
  console.log('Iteração', contador);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(contador), 200);
  });
}

function falha(contador) {
  contador++;
  console.log('Eu vou falhar na iteração', contador);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => rej(contador), 200);
  });
}

resolve(0)
  .then(resolve)
  .then(falha) // <-----------------
  .then(resolve) // nunca é chamada
  .catch(e => console.log('Erro no encadeamento!', e));
```

---

Portanto:

- para permitir a um encadeamento se recompor usa a função erro, e assim "apanhar" e tratar um possível erro usa a *função erro*
- para apanhar erros e de código que parte algures a meio usa o `.catch()` no final de um encadeamento.

O `.catch()` não é chamado se o erro for "tratado" e não houver uma nova Promise como retorno dessa função erro:

```js
function resolve(contador) {
  contador++
  console.log('Iteração', contador);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(contador), 200);
  });
}

function falha(contador) {
  contador++;
  console.log('Eu vou falhar na iteração', contador);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => rej(contador), 200);
  });
}

resolve(0)
  .then(resolve)
  .then(falha) // <-----------------
  .then(resolve) // nunca é chamada
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Serei chamado?');
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Houve erro?', err);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log('Erro no encadeamento!', e)); // não é chamado!
```

Por isso o `.catch()` funciona também como o ultimo recurso para reiniciar o encadeamento todo, ou pelo menos evitar *N* funções erro em cada nó do encadeamento.

Comment: Valeu! Entendi! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Abraços!

Comment: @Rafael de nada. Boa pergunta!